# Capturing internal Web Api service calls in a Web Application hosted in remote server

Tags: fiddler

My question may be weird but still I hope I can get some answer.
I have a Web Application hosted in a remote server A and I have a Web Api service hosted in a remote server B. The Web Application calls the Web Api service internally.
Now I have installed Fiddler in my local machine and I am accessing the Web Application from my local browser. Is there any way I can make Fiddler to Capture the internal Web Api http request though both are hosted in different servers ? Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

When you say "internally" I presume you mean that it's performing a HTTP request directly, not via JavaScript sent to the client?

If so, you start with this:
`[Client] -> [App on WebServerA] -> [WebAPI on ServerB]`

You then do this:
`[Client] -> [*Fiddler*] -> [App on ServerA] -> [WebAPI on ServerB]`

No, in that architecture, there's clearly no way for Fiddler to see traffic between ServerA and ServerB unless you change the configuration to:

`[Client] -> [App on ServerA] -> [*Fiddler*] -> [WebAPI on ServerB]`

That requires that you have control of either ServerA (where you'd configure its proxy settings to point to Fiddler, or control of ServerB (where you'd run Fiddler as a reverse-proxy to capture the inbound request.